# jquery - how to get unique data clicks for any anchor link

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which i want to display unquie counts for each anchor click I have within my #items div container. I have 6 links inside this container.  But everytime I click on a link, it doesn't increment.  It stays at 1.  What must I do to have the data count increment for each click?  fyi - counter should increment, even if you click the same link twice.

```
     $('#items a').data('counter', 0).on('click',function(e){
     var counter = $(this).data('counter'); 
     $(this).data('counter', counter + 1);

     console.log($(this).data('counter')); // increment value in developer tools.

        if ( $(this).data('counter') > 5) {
        console.log('your voting session has ended');
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#items a').remove();
        }
    });
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="items">
<a href="...">
<a href="...">
<a href="...">
<a href="...">
<a href="...">
<a href="...">
</div>
```

Comment: [Your code works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/webkb1y8/), assuming you want a separate counter per link.

Comment: no counter should increment even if you click the same link twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define data-counter on your markup at the start and increment value like:

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var counter = $(this).data('counter');
  if(counter<5) {
    counter++;
    $(this).data('counter', counter);
    $(this).html(counter);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-counter="0" href="#">0</a>
```